# Angular directive to use ng-blur and ng-focus

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble understanding Angular directives. I'd like to use a simple attribute to expand into more complicated html, but with some parts of this template being replaceable via parameters.

Given this code:

```
<form role="form" name="databaseForm">
    <input type="text" name="connectionName"
           ng-focus="databaseForm.connectionName.$focused = true;databaseForm.connectionName.$blurred = false;"
           ng-blur="databaseForm.connectionName.$blurred = true;databaseForm.connectionName.$focused = false;"
           >
</form>
```

I'd like to write it using a more terse directive (such as "blurred-focused"):

```
<form role="form" name="databaseForm">
    <input type="text" name="connectionName"
           blurred-focused="'databaseForm.connectionName'"
           >
</form>
```

So that means I can very easily re-use it for other inputs:

```
<form role="form" name="databaseForm">
    <input type="text" name="username"
           blurred-focused="'databaseForm.username'"
           >
</form>
```

The expected result from this is that the inputs with this directive will have the $blurred and $focused properties automatically applied to it, based on the user interaction with the input.

Thank you.

---

**Update:**
I ended up using MMHunter's version where the scope is non-isolated. I added some logic to automatically find the form and field object, so that I didn't need to specify it all.

My directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("app.shared.widgets")
    .directive("blurredFocused", blurredFocused);

    blurredFocused.$inject = ["_"];
    /* @ngInject */
    function blurredFocused(_) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            priority: -1,
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

                element.on("blur", function () {
                    var formFieldName = element[0].form.name + "." + element[0].name;
                    var target = _.get(scope, formFieldName);
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        target.$blurred = true;
                        target.$focused = false;
                    });

                });

                element.on("focus", function () {
                    var formFieldName = element[0].form.name + "." + element[0].name;
                    var target = _.get(scope, formFieldName);
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        target.$blurred = false;
                        target.$focused = true;
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }

})();
```

And an example of its usage:

```
<form role="form" name="databaseForm">
    <input type="text" name="connectionName" blurred-focused>
</form>
```

Comment: I really not understand what You need. Ng-focus and ng-blur are opposite directives, because blur=lost focus. ng-focus code is launched on focus ng blur on blur. Read about it - http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-focus.asp, http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-blur.asp

Comment: I basically wish to condense the syntax I have in first example into something more re-usable, without having to copy and paste that logic everywhere. What the logic does is sort of irrelevant to question. I'm aware that blur and focus are opposites, but I'd like both $blurred and $focused properties to be available with one single syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need is not difficult to achieve with angular directive. But things can be different based on whether isolated scope is used.

With isolated scope, the following code is straightForward. Binding the value to an isolated scope in the 'blurred-focused' directive and listen to the events.

```
//with isolated scope
app.directive("blurredFocused", [function () {
        return {
            restrict:"A",
            priority:-1,
            scope:{
              blurredFocused:"="
            },
            link:function(scope,ele,attrs){

                ele.on("blur",function(){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                      scope.blurredFocused.$blurred = true;
                      scope.blurredFocused.$focused = false;
                  })
                })

                ele.on("focus",function(){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.blurredFocused.$blurred = false;
                    scope.blurredFocused.$focused = true;
                  })
                })
            }
        }
    }]);
```

But without isolated scope, things could be a little bit tricky. we need to find the scope value manually by the attributes value.

```
//without isolated scope
app.directive("blurredFocused", [function () {
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        priority:-1,
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){

            ele.on("blur",function(){
              var targetField = scope[attrs.blurredFocused];
              scope.$apply(function(){
                targetField.$blurred = true;
                targetField.$focused = false;
              })

            })

            ele.on("focus",function(){
              var targetField = scope[attrs.blurredFocused];
              scope.$apply(function(){
                targetField.$blurred = false;
                targetField.$focused = true;
              })
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lv66Jv2poUriaeWd7pgM?p=preview)

I would recommend you use the one without isolated scope. Attribute directives are always used together so it may not be a good idea to have isolated scopes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any particular reason you use a priority of -1? Its my understanding that its setting the execution priority below the default value of 0. Is that some sort of best practice?

Comment: Well that doesn't matter much. Personally i usually use -1 in order to ensure  the behaviour is after other built-in or third-party directives.